# Is there something like Python's StringIO/CStringIO for C++?

Tags: c++, python, file, boost-serialization

I'm serializing a large amount of data to send over a network with Boost's serialization libraries.

Boost's serialization libraries require an intermediate file for serialization and deserialization. The volume of data being transmitted makes it awkward to do all of this. Keeping things in memory would be much better.

Is there anything at all in C++ similar to Python's cStringIO/StringIO that I can use to fake out Boost's serialization?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's called [`stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/).